# BasedOn=“{StaticResource {x:Type MY:MY_TYPE}}” throws exception saying resource cannot be found

Tags: wpf

I need to define a WPF style for one of our customized class (it is a class derived from ComboBox). However, when I added the line with `BasedOn` described in the title, I got the error saying resource cannot be found.

All the online articles say I can do such thing with system type, for example,

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}"
```

But how I can based on a customize control class?

BTW I have no problem using "MY:MY_TYPE" for e.g., declaring one control. Actually the IntelliSense even pops up the name "MY_TYPE" when I input the line for static resource. So it is not that I have some namespace problem.

Comment: Do you have a default style defined for `MY_TYPE` already? Only then you can use like in `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MY:MY_TYPE}}"`.

Comment: Silly question, have you tried restarting VS?